# Access & Modify user attribute "sub" in pre-signup lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools

In amplify there is an option user can sign-in through `preferred_username`. But During sign-up it is asking a username that is not `preferred_username` & that is immutable. After email conformation user can chose their `preferred_username`(it can be changed later on if that `preferred_username` available). Now user can sign-in through username(given during sign up),email & `preferred_username`(chosen after email conformation). Now this is very odd that one user have 2 username one is immutable and other is mutable.

**I WANT**

1. I want to access the sub(32 character unique user ID) in pre-signup lambda function.
2. Then I will pass a UUID in place of username instead of user choice because I don't want to tell the username to user that is required during sign-up. User should know only one username that is `preferred_username`.
3. Then in lambda function I will make sub=username(the username value will be assigned to sub that is a UUID) or if I can't modify sub I we will make it username=sub(the sub value will be assigned to username).

**MY QUESTION**

1. Is it possible to access sub in pre-signup function?(I tried but got error: `Cannot read properties of undefined`. I think there will be 2 possibilities either we can access or modify
   sub at any cost or there will be other method which I don't know).
2. Is it possible to modify username in pre-signup function?(I tried but got error: `Invalid user name. User name in Lambda mismatches the actual username.`. I think there will be other method).
3. Is there any limitations for social sign-in the things I am expecting?